# how to delete functionalitty with client confirmation in asp.net core mvc 6

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

i have a delete method but i don't know how to delete with client confirmation,
i have a method of delete

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id, bool? saveChangesError = false)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var student = await _context.userAccount
        .AsNoTracking()
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserID == id);
    if (student == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (saveChangesError.GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        ViewData["ErrorMessage"] =
            "Delete failed. Try again, and if the problem persists " +
            "see your system administrator.";
    }

    return View();
}

// POST: Students/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    try
    {
        UserAccount accToDelete = new UserAccount() { UserID = id };
        _context.Entry(accToDelete).State = EntityState.Deleted;
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
    {
        //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
        return RedirectToAction("Delete", new { id = id, saveChangesError = true });
    }
}
```

how to client confirmation on first click in asp.net core mvc 6.
any new idea or any modification

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud#update-the-delete-page

Comment: First, you need to have an html view to display related information about entity, in that view you need to have a button to delete and you can show a dialog or something like that, that button should to invoke action in controller, so in back-end you don't need to add confirmation, only in client side